# Apache VirtualHost conditional based on an environment variable

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I'm trying to include a config file inside an Apache 2.4 `<VirtualHost>` based on the presence of an environment variable.

Inside the `VirtualHost` declaration, I set the `VIEWMODE` environment variable as such:

```
Define virtualhost_config "${virtualhost_path}/conf/virtualhost.conf"
<VirtualHost *:80>
        SetEnv VIEWMODE demo
        Include "${virtualhost_config}"
</VirtualHost>
```

Inside the included config file, I now have this conditional inside the `<Directory>` block:

```
<If "env('VIEWMODE') == 'demo'">
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.apple.com/ [L,R=302]
</If>
```

However, I can't seem to get this to work. The conditional `RewriteRule` is ignored.

What am I missing?

Comment: use `Redirect 302 "http://www.apple.com/"` inside the `If`, otherwise I'm not sure it would work without `RewriteEngine On` there.

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation for `SetEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv):

> The internal environment variables set by this directive are set *after* most early request processing directives are run, such as access control and URI-to-filename mapping. If the environment variable you're setting is meant as input into this early phase of processing such as the `RewriteRule` directive, you should instead set the environment variable with `SetEnvIf`.

And the [note about environment variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#functions) within the functions section of the Apache Expresions documentation is also of interest:

> **Environment variable ordering**
>
> When environment variables are looked up within an `<If>` condition, it's important to consider how extremely early in request processing that this resolution occurs. As a guideline, any directive defined outside of virtual host context (directory, location, htaccess) is not likely to have yet had a chance to execute. `SetEnvIf` in virtual host scope is one directive that runs prior to this resolution
>
> When `reqenv` is used outside of `<If>`, the resolution will generally occur later, but the exact timing depends on the directive the expression has been used within.

So you need to use [`SetEnvIf`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) because `SetEnv` is not processed soon enough, and that fixed it for me when I tested here. Something like:

```
Define virtualhost_config "${virtualhost_path}/conf/virtualhost.conf"
<VirtualHost *:80>
        SetEnvIf Request_URI ^ VIEWMODE=demo
        Include "${virtualhost_config}"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting an Apache variable, which then fed both the `SetEnv` directive as well as the `<If>` block. Unfortunately, the `<If>` block itself seemed to cause issues with the processing order of directives *inside it* (e.g. `ServerAlias not allowed here`), but `<IfDefine>` did not have this problem (using `<IfDefine>` only worked for me because `VIEWMODE` was binary). The final solution looked something like this:

```
Define environment production
Define viewmode demo

<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv ENVIRONMENT ${environment}
    <IfDefine viewmode>
        SetEnv VIEWMODE ${viewmode}
        Include "${virtualhost_path}/conf/demo-configuration.conf"
    </IfDefine>
</VirtualHost>

UnDefine environment
UnDefine viewmode
```

An important caveat is that Apache variables are *global*, so if the same variables might be used in subsequent Virtual Hosts, make sure to `UnDefine` them at the end of each config.